# Finding non-eager loaded relations used in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I've inherited a medium sized legacy app that was quickly built to address a customer's need. Luckily it was well written for the most part but because it was rushed there are a lot of places that ActiveRecord relations were not eager loaded. As the traffic of the site starts to increase, these n+1 bugs are really starting to surface.

My question is how can I easily find these problems and write something to the logs or generate a report, anything to alert me and other devs while developing?

What I have so far is an object that can wrap around any view or template that is being rendered:

```
class EagerLoadIssueLogger
  def track(&block)
    # Start tracking eager load issues
    result = block.call
    # Stop tracking eager load issues
    result
  end
end
```

Then call in a layout or view like so:

```
<body>
   <%= @eager_load_tracker.track { yield } %>
</body>
```

My issue is I can't figure out how to determine when an association is called that hasn't been eager loaded. I know there is a method `loaded?` that I can use to check any one relation like:

```
@team.users.loaded? # returns true or false
```

but I want to check any relation loaded while in my tracker block and if not loaded, log it, otherwise, good job, just ignore. I know I can probably accomplish this by monkey-patching into `ActiveRecord::Relation` or some other `ActiveRecord` class/module but have been fruitlessly searching for where to get started.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) can be used to log n+1 queries. It works pretty well for me.

Comment: Wow, that gem exceeds my expectations. Can't wait to kill those n+1 queries, thanks.